# After save Javascript file in VScode, it changed all format

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am having a problem with my vscode that I hope someone can help me. When I try to save a javascript file, it changed all the formating. So, I have to change the language mode from Javascript to Javascript React to all of .js files to make it looks normal. Do you have any suggestions?

Before saving

```
   const FormComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Hello </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormComponent;
```

After saving

```
const FormComponent = () => {
    return ( <
        div className = "container" >
        <
        h1 > Hello < /h1> <
        /div>
    );
};

export default FormComponent;
```

in settings.json

```
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
```

Comment: VS Code has two division of settings - User & workspace. Any settings in workspace overrides user settings. Make sure `"editor.formatOnSave": false` in workspace settings too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `editor.formatOnSave` to `true`

Change it to `false` as it formats the file on saving

Comment: I changed it, but it still the same.

Comment: restart vscode. then create new javascript file and try